# Dynamically adding methods to a class

Tags: python

I'm trying to add methods to a class based on a list.

```
class _Roles(object):
    """
    set the roles for dev, staging and production
    """
    def __init__(self):
        from types import MethodType
        steps = ['dev','stage','prod']
        for step in steps:
            def env_setter(self):
                print step
            method = MethodType(env_setter,self,self.__class__)
            setattr(self,step,method)
```

The problem is that when I call `_Roles.dev()`, `_Roles.stage()`, or `_Roles.prod()`, I always get printed the last step that is **prod** instead of getting **dev** for `dev()` and so on. what's the reason for this?

Comment: I think it would be a better design if you just define different classes (perhaps using subclassing) for the different roles., then dynamically select the right class in a function or mapping.

Comment: Another problem here is you are setting the method on the instance, and not the class. But.. this kind of monkey-patching is hard to debug and maintain. I would recommend avoiding it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because [you use the same scope for all function declarations](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/502271-these-nasty-closures-caveats-for-the-closure-enthu/). Define each function in a separate scope.

Comment: hi thanks, in that case how can i set the 'step' parameter on the function before i bound the method?

Comment: Create another scope. Like within a function. That you pass `step` to.

Comment: but MethodType requires a callable function :/

Comment: So return a callable function from that scope. What's the problem? There are many other alternatives, the best one involving rewriting your code so you don't need to do this in the first place, but @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams has the right answer if you really want to do things this way.

Answer (score 27):

Just use `setattr` :

```py
class Foo:
    def __init__(self, v):
        self.v = v
        
def my_new_method(self):
    print("self.v =", self.v)

setattr(Foo, 'print_v', my_new_method)

Foo(5).print_v()
```

Output :

> self.v = 5

Comment: Why not much simpler and more readable `Foo.print_v = my_new_method`?

Comment: @panda-34 my solution also works if you have several new methods to add based on a list of strings (i.e. `setattr` in a `for` loop)

Comment: This is good for instance methods.  Is there a way for class methods?

Answer (score 1):

[The link provided by Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams](https://code.activestate.com/recipes/502271-these-nasty-closures-caveats-for-the-closure-enthu/) neatly explains why closures don't work inside an iterator. The solution is to create a new namespace for each closure, by calling a helper function and passing it the relevant variables. Adopted to python 3 this can look like this:

```py
class _Roles:
    """
    set the roles for dev, staging and production
    """

    @staticmethod
    def make_env_setter(step):
        def env_setter(self):
            print(step)

        return env_setter

    def __init__(self):
        from types import MethodType

        steps = ["dev", "stage", "prod"]
        for step in steps:

            env_setter = self.make_env_setter(step)

            method = MethodType(env_setter, self)
            setattr(self, step, method)
```